# How do I determine confidence intervals around weighted, probilized events?

Tags: probability

How would I go about finding out the confidence intervals around a set of distinct bianary occurrences where each occurence has a different associated probability and each occurence is weighted?

To be more specific, we typically determine a milestone budget by assigning reasonable probabilities to each milestone.  Each milestone typically usually has a differnt probability of success and a different dollar value.  For example if we need to determine the amount of money we need to hold out for 3 milestones, we would do this:
$$P(\text{milestone}_1) \text{cost}(\text{milestone}_1)+P(\text{milestone}_2) \text{cost}(\text{milestone}_2)+\dots $$
So it could look something like this:  Budget = (10% x $\$$1,000,000) + (50% x $\$$5,000,000) + (20% x $\$$20,000,000) = $\$$6,600,000.

Each milestone is bianary in that it either happens or it doesn't.  so for the first milestone, we are saying that there is a 10% chance that we will need to pay $\$$1M dollars and a 90% chance that we will pay nothing.

Obviously, we won't ever actually be paying the probilized amount of $\$$6.6M.  How would I go about determining the probability range around where the spend is most likely to fall.  In other words, if I wanted to demonstrate where the actual spend might fall with a certainty of 80% how would I go about calculating this?  Note that we have more events in my real world problem...

Thanks in advance for any help.  I am not a statistician at all so please forgive my ignorance and any lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you would need to make a [probability tree](http://www.google.com/search?q=probability+tree) with resulting penalty sums in leafs and sum the whole thing up for a criterion of your choice, possibly using some software for more milestones than few (there will be $2^N$ leafs for $N$ milestones). You will be able to build the distribution too.

For a really huge number of milestones, you'd need a Monte Carlo simulation, so basically just simulate the process huge number of times (using random number generator to decide whether to fire or not certain milestone) and then obtain a histogram of outputs as a distribution approximation.

Comment: Thanks MBQ!  As I mentioned to Henry, I can already table out all of the different possibilities using a macro, I should be able to create the tree that you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on how many milestones you have.  But if this (call it $n$) is small enough and each one either happens or does not, then you can work out the $2^n$ possibilities, working out the probabilities by multiplying the inidividual probabilies.

So for example the probability of paying out $20,000,000$ is $0.9 \times 0.5 \times 0.2 = 0.09$ or 9%.

You then sort by value and add up the probabilities, to find for example that the probability of paying $20,000,000$ *or less* is $0.89$; adding up in reverse you find the probability of paying $20,000,000$ *or more* is $0.20$.

Your table might look like this

```
Prob    CumProb RevCum  Amount

0.36    0.36    1.00            0
0.04    0.40    0.64    1,000,000
0.36    0.76    0.60    5,000,000
0.04    0.80    0.24    6,000,000
0.09    0.89    0.20   20,000,000
0.01    0.90    0.11   21,000,000
0.09    0.99    0.10   25,000,000
0.01    1.00    0.01   26,000,000
```

This will then let you make statements about confidence.

Comment: Thank you very much Henry!  this is most helpful.  I had already written an excel maro that gave me all of the combinations without replacement (essentially, the table you suggest) but I didn't know what to do with the data.  Thanks again for your time and help!